# How to find not valid email accounts?

Tags: civimail

I have CiviCRM 4.4.2. When I send mailings to fictitious email addresses, CiviCRM doesn't return any error. In the report, everything looks fine (100% successful deliveries).

It is important to clean all the emails that are no valid anymore.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds as though bounce processing isn't set up correctly. See:

[Bounce Handling](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Bounce+Handling)

[Setting Up the Return Channel](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviMail+Installation#CiviMailInstallation-SettingUptheReturnChannel)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on 4.4.2 I'd strongly encourage you to upgrade before doing much else.

Civi doesn't know those are invalid email addresses until something tells it so.  It hands off the mail to the mail system and, if something goes wrong, a bounce mail is generated which can be processed and used to update Civi.   The details depend on how you are sending mail.

If you are sending mail directly, then you need a bounce processor - see https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/#configuring-inbound-email-processing

Alternatively if you use something like Sparkpost and https://civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost-email-extension-for-civicrm then bounces are handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a nifty email amender that automatically cleans email addresses as they're added. You can set the rules yourself :) let me know how you get on http://github.com/johnff you'll have to clean up currently existing addresses yourself though.